# Network hickups right now?

Tags: bug

The last few minutes (half an hour perhaps?) none of the SE sites answer to HTTP. This is the first one to come up again.

Yes, my Internet connection to the US is working fine, even to the US. While it was down:

```
$ traceroute to meta.stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.16), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 [delete, irrelevant anyway]
 6  po3-40G.ar4.NYC1.gblx.net (67.17.108.246)  139.671 ms  129.079 ms  130.511 ms
 7  67.17.192.54 (67.17.192.54)  135.406 ms  135.191 ms  135.501 ms
 8  border1.po2-20g-bbnet2.nym008.pnap.net (216.52.95.65)  197.202 ms  134.998 ms border1.po1-20g-bbnet1.nym008.pnap.net (216.52.95.1)  134.775 ms
 9  stackexchange-1.border1.nym008.pnap.net (74.201.252.22)  195.771 ms  134.743 ms  134.490 ms
```

Right now this is the only site responding.

Comment: OK, the sites came up again (but are quite slow).

Comment: It's not you.  While they were down, I checked from three external uptime services and the stackexchange sites were not responding to any of them.

Comment: [We are aware of the site issues at the moment and are working together with our ISP on a solution.](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/313123103146401793)

Comment: @Yannis, thanks. No criticism implied/explied, just wanted to let you know.

Comment: @Yannis, Ironically, that status tweet is not showing on the https://twitter.com/StackStatus page at the moment. ;-)   **Update:** After 22 minutes, it now shows on the StackStatus twitter page.